# How to store a connection state in Vue3?

Tags: javascript, node.js, frontend, vuejs3

I'm new sorry if I don't know how to write a help request.

I've created a ToDoList in Vue3 and NodeJs, I've already setted my backend, so now I work on my front.

I have a problem with my Vue script, I want to store my connection state, so when I push the button Login, the button "Créer une tache" appears, and my login button transform into a logout button in my Navigation bar

So my problem, is when I change my view I go for example in "Liste des tâches" my button "Créer une tâche" and "Logout" disappear.

Thank's for the future answers !

So this is my Navbar.vue script :

```
<template> 
  <nav class="navbar-light bg-light">
    <ul class="ul1">
      <li><router-link to="/"> <button id="inscription-button" class="btn inscription-button"> Accueil  </button> </router-link></li>
      <li><router-link to="/informations" id="inscription-button" class="btn inscription-button"> Informations </router-link></li>
      <li><router-link to="/tasklist" id="inscription-button" class="btn inscription-button"> Liste de tâches </router-link></li>
      <router-link to="/createtask" v-if="isLoggedIn" id="inscription-button" class="btn inscription-button"> Créer une tâche </router-link>  
      <li><router-link to="/contact" id="inscription-button" class="btn inscription-button"> Contact </router-link></li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
      <li v-if="!navLoggedIn">
        <router-link to="/login">Login</router-link>
      </li>
      <li v-if="navLoggedIn">
        <button @click="logout">Logout</button>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</template>

<script>
import { mapActions, mapState } from 'vuex';

export default {
  data() {
  return{
  
    navLoggedIn : false
  }
},
  props: {
    isLoggedIn:  Boolean,
    
  },
  name: 'Navbar',
  methods: {
    ...mapActions('navbar', { logout: 'logout' }),
  },
  async mounted(){
    this.navLoggedIn=this.isLoggedIn
  },
  watch: {
    // whenever question changes, this function will run
    isLoggedIn(newvalue) {
      this.navLoggedIn =newvalue;
    }
  },
};
</script>
```

and this is my Login.vue script :

```
<template>
  <navbar :isLoggedIn="return_log()"></navbar>

  <section class="vh-100">
<div class="container py-5 h-100">
  <div class="row d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center h-100">
    <div class="col-md-8 col-lg-7 col-xl-6">
      <img src="https://mdbcdn.b-cdn.net/img/Photos/new-templates/bootstrap-login-form/draw2.svg"
        class="img-fluid" alt="Phone image">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-7 col-lg-5 col-xl-5 offset-xl-1">
      <form @submit.prevent="submitForm">

        <div class="form-outline mb-4">
          <input type="email" id="form1Example13" class="form-control form-control-lg"  required v-model="email" name="user_mail" />
          <label class="form-label" for="form1Example13">Adresse email</label>
        </div>

        <div class="form-outline mb-4">
          <input type="password" id="form1Example23" class="form-control form-control-lg" required v-model="password" name="user_password" />
          <label class="form-label" for="form1Example23" >Mot de passe</label>
        </div>

        <div class="d-flex justify-content-around align-items-center mb-4">

          <div class="form-check">
            <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="" id="form1Example3" checked />
            <label class="form-check-label" for="form1Example3"> Se souvenir de moi </label>
          </div>
          <a href="#!">Mot de passe oublié ?</a>
        </div>

        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block">Se connecter</button>

        <div class="divider d-flex align-items-center my-4">
        </div>

      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</section>

</template>

<script>
import { mapActions } from "vuex";
import Navbar from "../components/Navbar.vue"
import Swal from 'sweetalert2'
export default {
components: {Navbar},
// props: {
//   isLoggedIn: {
//     type: Boolean,
//     required: true
//   }
// },
data() {
  return{
    email:'',
    password:'',
    isLoggedIn : false
  }
},
methods: {
  return_log : function(){
    return this.isLoggedIn
  },
  submitForm: async function () { 
    const response = await this.login({
      email:this.email,
      password:this.password
    });

    if(response.success) {
      Swal.fire({
        title: 'Connexion réussie ! ',
        text: response.message,
        icon: 'success'
      });

      this.isLoggedIn= true
      // this.$router.push('/tasklist')
    }
    else{
      Swal.fire({
        title: 'Connexion échouée ',
        text: response.message,
        icon: 'error'
      });
    }
  },
  ...mapActions("requests/auth", ["login"]),
}
}
</script>
```

I tried to add in my App.vue my navbar to get my connection state stored in all my views.

Comment: Maybe you could use Layout components and router components.After imported the router you could control changing one part of view of full page by url changes.And the other parts of this page will not change.Of course,the login page will take over the whole page.

Comment: I don't fully, understand. Can you give me more precisions ?